# Yosemite Double Login

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, login

I just bought myself a Macbook Air and its the first time I own Mac hardware.

I have registered with My apple account and the issue I am getting is that when I boot the machine I have to login twice.

Once with the Apple ID credentials, and the second time with the Administrator account of the machine.

There is another issue. When I registered I had made a mistake typing in the Apple ID name, now this wrong name appears in the first login even though I have changed it in the apple ID webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found that the problem. On setting up I activated disk encryption in Filevault with the previous account.

The solution is to decrypt and re-encrypt the the disk with current Apple ID.